# How to maintain list of contributors and their contribution?

Tags: solidity, ether, mapping

In my smart contract I have a map which map a person and his/her contribution. Say for example `a` contributes 20 ether, `b` contributes 10 ether. Everything works fine, but when I checking it shows:

```
{
    "0": "address: contributor 0x4b0897b0513fdc7c541b6d9d7e929c4e5364d2db",
    "1": "uint256: amount 20000000000000000000"
}
```

But actually he contributed 20 ether only. How can I maintain the exact amount? So, finally I can return their exact amount. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That value is 20 ether. Indeed, 20000000000000000000 wei = 20 ether. So it's correct

https://etherconverter.online/

Comment: So if I send that much wei will it reduce only 20 ether..

Comment: yes, the amounts are stored in wei.